# Redirect Episerver Form to Payment Page on Submission

Tags: episerver, optimizely, episerver-forms

I'm seeking advice on how to essentially redirect an Episerver form to a payment page immediately after submission, including the form's field information (amount and number). The goal is to redirect the user to a payment gateway when they click "Make Payment," passing along the input from the Episerver form. Essentially, I want to redirect to the payment page with the field information on submission, and let the payment gateway handle the rest.

[image: Form Fields]

I attempted to use the "Trigger webhook after submission" option, but unfortunately, it didn't work as expected.

[image]

I'm curious if Episerver provides a built-in mechanism to achieve this, or if customization of the form submission method through code changes is necessary. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

THis is where the form submission redirect which is a payment gateway with epi form fields
[image]

Comment: What happens in that webhook? If you have the form POST to an endpoint on the site, you can pretty much anything you want with the data.

Comment: Once i submit the form,it says "Forms submitted succesfully & nothing else. What I am looking for is ,the submit button should basically act as a checkout option  with the form details to the payment gateway where it has all the payment details to be added &  proceed with the payment there.

Comment: Did you set up an endpoint that the form submits to? If so, what does the code for the endpoint look like?

Comment: I added the payment gateway url to the WebHook url section within episerver form setting section (screenshot attached in the post above) & since this is a payment gateway that's  third party so don't have any control over the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question how the payment gateway expects to receive the information it needs to process the payment. I'll assume that you can send it via querystring for the purposes of this answer.

---

To modify the URL you post to you can override the `BuildReturnResultForSubmitAction` method on `DataSubmissionService`.

Register dependency:

```
context.Services.AddTransient<DataSubmissionService, CustomDatasubmissionService>();
```

Inherit and override:

```
public class CustomDatasubmissionService : DataSubmissionService
{
    protected override SubmitActionResult BuildReturnResultForSubmitAction(bool isJavaScriptSupport, bool isSuccess,
                                            string message, HttpContextBase httpContext, FormContainerBlock formContainer = null, Dictionary<string, object> additionalParams = null,
                                            SubmissionInfo submissionInfo = null, Submission submission = null, bool isProgressiveSubmit = false, string redirectUrl = "")
    {
        var baseResult = base.BuildReturnResultForSubmitAction(isJavaScriptSupport, isSuccess, message, httpContext, formContainer, additionalParams, submissionInfo, submission, isProgressiveSubmit, redirectUrl);
        if (isSuccess) // only set redirect url when sucesss
        {
          // specify your own URL
          baseResult.RedirectUrl = "http://google.com";
        }

        return baseResult;
    }
}
```

The values from the form submission is available in `submissionInfo`.

Keep in mind that this code would execute for all form submissions so additional checks would be needed to only run the redirect logic for specific forms.

Code in this answer modified from this post on Optimizely World: https://world.optimizely.com/forum/developers-add-ons-forum/Forms/thread-container/2018/11/redirect-user-from-custom-actor-to-dynamically-generated-url/

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the response. I do get that custom implementation is 1 way to go for this .However, what i was trying to find is, if this can be achieved without code changes especially when epi forms has Trigger webhook after form submission.

Comment: No built in way that I know of. A webhook won't perform a redirect and if you use form's redirect after submit functionality you won't be able to send parametners along.